# SSRS-Access reports from other system without authentication

Tags: reporting-services

I am viewing a report using SSRS in my server. My server is generally password protected. Each time if I want to see the reports from another local system in the same network, I need to enter the username and password of the server. I cannot share the server password with everyone. So I want to view the reports directly without user authentication. How to perform this??

Comment: Use a webpage with a reportviewer. Add the passwords into the config and go from there.

Comment: @Snowlockk   can you please brief it because i am not able to understand

Comment: You can create an internal website with the reportviewer control. Using a class like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportservercredentials.aspx you can store the credentials and not have to hand them out. When the users navigate to the reportviewer page they can see the reports but not have to insert username or password.